# Getting Error executing command and make sure you have ant installed and add to your path

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant

I added all the paths that needed.
I read Android Platform Guide from Apache Cordova over and over again, And I just can't find the answer.

I have search similar problems in stackoverflow but it didn't help or the answer was for
ant that was not recognize at all in cmd.

Here is my cmd with the error:

"Error: ERROR : executing command and make sure you have ant installed and add to your path"

[image]

As you can see, 'ant -version' working just fine, but cordova just can't recognize it..

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fix it by adding this line:

```
"C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows\System;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;"
```

In **Environments Variables** -> edit "**Path**" variable and append this line inside value.

Done. :-)